# Javascript - Pre-fill form of website that isn't mine

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to load a website like google.com and edit the page using javascript because I have to pre-fill a form on a site that isn't mine..

I saw I can use `window.location.assign()` method to go to an another page but I want to interact with it.
I don't want to use extension or something like that.

Please, if anybody know how to do this, help me !

Yours sincerely.

Comment: You can use a userscript, but *I don't want to use extension or something like that.* userscript managers *are* extensions. But your only other alternative is to type directly into the console

Comment: Thanks ! I can't just load a page and interact with it in only one script ?

Comment: With a userscript, sure you can, but a userscript manager is an extension, and you said you didn't want to use an extension

Comment: In my case, I can't use an extension.

Comment: Guess all you can do is copy-paste into the console manually

Comment: I can't do that too.. That's why I'm here :) Thanks for your proposals

Comment: If you can't do anything to the page *or* the browser, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Ok.. So bad.. I can do that with iframes ?

Comment: Not if the site has cross-site scripting protection, which it almost certainly does

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot for those informations !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they disable XSS then no. You would need to use an extension like `userscript`.

If somehow they don't disable XSS (cross-site scripting) then you could try to load in an I-frame and use a scripting language like javascript (though I'd recommend you use jQuery for simple DOM Manipulation/traversing).